# Problem downloading a zip file from a web site using Java

Tags: java, groovy, grails

I am trying to download 6 firmware zip files from a website. Four of the files download fine and I can extract the files from the downloaded zips. But 2 of the zip files end up only 75Kb, (instead of around 8Mb) and are corrupted/invalid.  If I go to the website and download the failed files using my browser, (by clicking the download link), they download just fine.

I have a grails/groovy app, but am using Java to do the download.

I've tried 2 different methods to do this. The first is :-

```
    URL url = new URL("https://thewebsite.com/filestore/thefile.zip");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("c:\mydownloadedfile\thefile.zip");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
```

This was fine for 4 of the zip files on the site, but 2 particular files failed in the sense that I ended up with a 75kb file which was invalid. And so I also tried this method :-

```
    Files.copy(
            new URL("https://thewebsite.com/filestore/thefile.zip").openStream(),
            Paths.get("c:\mydownloadedfile\thefile.zip"))
```

...but this resulted in exactly the same problem. 4 zips downloaded ok, but 2 of the files resulted in 75kb files which were invalid files.  And the 2 files that failed to  download using my code actually download fine if I go to the site and use my browser to download them.

I'm not getting any errors reported in my app at all, so I'm at a loss as to whats going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the downloads, the content? Is it really the beginning
of a ZIP-File (and therefor an incomplete download) or is the content
the HTML for an error 4XX or 5XX or for a 3XX forward?

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks!  I've just done that, and lo and behold, its not a zip file. Its a bunch of html. So I renamed the .zip to .html and viewed it in my browser, and surprise surprise I get a lovely formatted page saying the page I requested could not be found.  So nothing wrong with my code (I'll leave it here for others who might be interested), its a problem with where the files are on the web site.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you figured it out.  It's not returning a 200.  BUT, you do have a bug in the code that could be triggered at some point.  You are basically doing the coding equivalent of "not flushing and leaving the seat up."  More concretely if there IS an exception thrown those streams won't be closed and file handles will be left open.  And, if you used any Buffered streams (ie `BufferedOutputStream`) you could leave bytes left in memory that don't get written to your file (in your code you aren't doing that, but should it change that defect could creep in).

```
    URL url = new URL("https://thewebsite.com/filestore/thefile.zip");
    try( BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()) ) {
       try( FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("c:\mydownloadedfile\thefile.zip") ) {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int count = 0;
          while ((count = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
             fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
          }
       }
    }
```

If you switch to using the try-resource syntax then Java will close those streams for you appropriately even when exceptions are thrown so no resources will leak.  And, it will flush the buffers should you use anything like `BufferedOutputStream` keeping the stream from loosing data left in memory.  Plus you don't have to write `fis.close()` and `bis.close()` which makes things a bit tidier.

Another suggestion is crank up your buffer size.  With modern computers come with 8MiB to 4GiB of disk buffer size. You can see IO improved performance by using larger buffers like 16kb or higher.  So `byte[] buffer = new byte[2 << 15]` will give you a boost in speed.

If you want to get the Response Code for the Http connection you can do the following:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
if( code == 200 ) {
   InputStream urlStream = new BufferedInputStream( url.openStream() );
   // do the logic above
} else {
   // bad URL, or whatever!
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to post this information. Really helpful, and I'll certainly tidy up what I'm doing in my code.  I have stumbled across another problem now though (trying to get around the links being inconsistent on the web page) which I've posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77747699/unable-to-fully-parse-an-html-page-with-groovy-grails